# Почему не отрабатывает функция JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня следующий код:

```js
  html = [];
  function addTagInfo() {
    html.push("<div class='row'> \
      <div class='col-md-4'> \
        <div class='form-group'> \
          <label for='usr'>Тег на странице:</label> \
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
      <div class='col-md-4'> \
        <div class='form-group'> \
          <label for='usr'>Название переменной:</label> \
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
      <div class='col-md-4'> \
        <div class='form-group'> \
          <label for='usr'>Название для CSV:</label> \
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
    </div>");
    html.push("<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='addTagInfo()'>Еще тег</button>");
  }

  url.onblur = function() {
    function isURL(str) {
      var urlPattern = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?"); // fragment locator
      if(!urlPattern .test(str)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (!isURL(this.value)) { // введено не число
      // показать ошибку
      this.className = "error";
      error.innerHTML = 'Вы ввели не url. Исправьте, пожалуйста.'
    } else {
      addTagInfo();
      html.push("<div class='form-group'> \
        <label for='isSCV'>Создать ли CSV:</label> \
        <input type='checkbox' class='form-control' id='isSCV'> \
      </div>");
      html.push("<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Парсить</button>");
      $('#parser').append(html.join(''));
    }
  };
  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Заполните нижеследующие поля:</p>
  <form id="parser">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Url:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url">
    </div>
    <div id="error"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

А функция, которая должна запускать при нажатии на кнопку "Еще тег", почему-то не отрабатывает. Чтобы поля появились при выполнении кода достаточно вставить любую валидную ссылку.

Comment: Вставлял несколько видов валидных ссылок, так и не прошел валидацию :(

Comment: у автора ссылки без префикса www являются невалидными

Comment: Ох, я поправлю этот недочет.

Comment: Функция добавляет в html элемент, но не выводит его в контейнер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, моя правка кода противоречит задумке, но функция добавляла в переменную html элемент, но потом не вставляла этот html в контейнер.

```js
html = [];
  function addTagInfo() {
    html.push("<div class='row'> \
      <div class='col-md-4'> \
        <div class='form-group'> \
          <label for='usr'>Тег на странице:</label> \
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
      <div class='col-md-4'> \
        <div class='form-group'> \
          <label for='usr'>Название переменной:</label> \
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
      <div class='col-md-4'> \
        <div class='form-group'> \
          <label for='usr'>Название для CSV:</label> \
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
    </div>");
    html.push("<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='addTagInfo()'>Еще тег</button>");
    $('#parser').append(html.join(''));
    html = [];
  }

  url.onblur = function() {
    function isURL(str) {
      var urlPattern = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?"); // fragment locator
      if(!urlPattern .test(str)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (!isURL(this.value)) { // введено не число
      // показать ошибку
      this.className = "error";
      error.innerHTML = 'Вы ввели не url. Исправьте, пожалуйста.'
    } else {
      addTagInfo();
      html.push("<div class='form-group'> \
        <label for='isSCV'>Создать ли CSV:</label> \
        <input type='checkbox' class='form-control' id='isSCV'> \
      </div>");
      html.push("<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Парсить</button>");
      $('#parser').append(html.join(''));
      
    }
  };
  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Заполните нижеследующие поля:</p>
  <form id="parser">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Url:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url">
    </div>
    <div id="error"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите, а как можно сделать одну глобальную переменную? Чтобы добавлялось один раз - в else.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov Не понимаю, как можно сделать добавление 1 раз, если их как минимум 2. Первоначальный вывод и добавление. Для решения какой задачи вообще используется эта переменная?

Comment: Пишу парсер. Эти данные потом пойдут как материал для него.

Comment: Сейчас создал дополнительную переменную, но нормальный ли это путь?

Comment: Трудно сказать, т.к. я все еще не знаю цель записи html в переменную. Она потом куда-то передается? Возможно, стоит делать append без переменной. + Я бы еще делал remove кнопки.

Comment: Нет, не передается. Но я все понял, спасибо.